# How do I get the width and height of an image stored inside a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, image, javascript-objects

I am looking of a way to find the dimensions of the passed in image.
When I log the height and width it returns 0 for both.

```
function GamePiece(imageName){
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = imageName;
    this.width = this.image.width;
    this.height = this.image.height;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow the browser time to load the image before you can get it's size.  You can use the `onload` callback to detect when the image is loaded.

```
function GamePiece(imageName){
    var gamePiece = this;

    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.onload = function() {
        gamePiece.width = this.width;
        gamePiece.height = this.height;
    }
    this.image.src = imageName;
}
```

There will be a delay before the callback is run and the dimensions are set on your object.